# Fetch multiple securities from Yahoo using Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, fetch

I an trying to fetch multiple securities from Yahoo using Matlab. Since Yahoo does not support multiple fetch, so loops is used as following code:

```
ticker = { 'AAPL' 'MSFT' 'XOM' 'GE' 'JNJ'  'BRK.B' 'WFC' 'AMZN' 'JPM' 'FB' };
c=yahoo;

for i=1:10
Price.(ticker(i)) = fetch(c,ticker(i), 'Adj Close', 'Jan 1 05', 'Dec 31 07', 'm');
temp = Price.(ticker(i));
ClosePrice(:, i) =temp(:,2);
end 

close(c);
```

But Matlab gives error message "Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name."

Does anyone have any insight to fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using dynamical referencing in a structure on this line:

```
Price.(ticker(i)) = ...
```

On each loop, the part in parentheses should evaluate to a string so that you effectively get `Price.AAPL` on the first iteration, `Price.MSFT` on the second, `Price.XOM` on the third, and so on. However, `ticker` is a cell array so you have to be careful using () vs {}. Using () gives you a subset of a cell array, effectively another cell array. On the other hand, using {} returns you the actual **content** of the cell array. To fix your code, replace any instances of `(ticker(i))` with `(ticker{i})`.

Comment: Wonderful, It works! I knew something minor but very tricky caused the problem and could't figure out the intricacy. Your answer absolutely crystallize the issue!  A big THANK YOU!